# MediaWiki setup is unable to log into root@localhost DB, but I can log into it via SSH

Tags: mediawiki, mysql

I'm setting up MediaWiki on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. After installing the `mediawiki` package I went to web installer and got to the "Connect to database" step. I'm using the following settings:

- Database host: `localhost`
- Database name: `testwiki`
- Database table prefix:
- Database username: `root`
- Database password: `fubar`

I can SSH into the server, and I used `mysqladmin -u root password` to set the root password to `fubar`. I can log into MariaDB using `mysql -u root -p` and inputting `fubar` when prompted. I can see that MariaDB is running properly using `service mysql status`.

However, when I try to progress through the MediaWiki installer, I get the following error:

> DB connection error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (localhost).
>
> Check the host, username and password and try again.

What do I need to change here? The password entered in the web installer matches the root password used to log into the database.

Comment: A very late comment: I am not very experienced and had a similar problem. I solved it by creating an ordinary user account for the database and assigning the access to MediaWiki through the configuration page. I spent hours googling a solution to access through root account, the divergent answers indicated to me that it is not a straightforward issue.

Answer (score 2):

For newer mediawiki versions, there are some pitfalls that breaks the mysql connection. Some attempts to fix are:

1. Insert the port number on Database Host:

```
$wgDBserver = "localhost:3306";
```

2. On some old LocalSettings.php, there are active configurations for PostgreSQL besides the Mysql config. Erase or comment it.

```
# Postgres specific settings
# $wgDBport           = "5432";
# $wgDBmwschema       = "mediawiki";
# $wgDBts2schema      = "public";
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are required to create the `testwiki` database manually, as well as a `testadmin` user with its own password, then manually give `testadmin` permissions on `testwiki`. Doing that solved the problem.